# Vue.js - How to implement Computed properties on objects of array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, computed-properties

I have an array of objects inside my Vue instance, and for each item I'd like to write a Computed property.

Each object has only two properties: `firstName` and `lastName`. I would like to write a Computed property for each named 'fullName', which is just a concatenation of `firstName` and `lastName`.

I'm familiar with implementing Computed properties of data object properties of a Vue instances, but when it comes to doing so with elements of an array, I get confused.

Currently, my code is this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    names: [{
        firstName: 'Mike',
        lastName: 'McDonald',
        done: false
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Alex',
        lastName: 'Nemeth',
        done: false
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Nate',
        lastName: 'Kostansek',
        done: true
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Ivan',
        lastName: 'Wyrsta',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    fullName: function(name) {
      return name.lastName + ', ' + name.firstName;
    }      
  }
  methods: {
    toggle: function(name) {
      name.done = !name.done;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <ol>
    <li v-for='name in names'>
      <input type='checkbox' v-bind:checked='name.done' v-on:change='toggle(name)' />
      <span v-if='!name.done'>{{ fullName(name) }}</span>
      <del v-else>{{ fullName(name) }}</del>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

And here is the respective [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SirToadstool/dncyx37t/8/)

Comment: Try to reduce the number of function calls in your template. The function results are not cached, meaning that pretty much every change in data causes a full re-render. Using a computed, by creating an array of pre-computed objects can greatly improve your apps performance. See @Boussadjra's updated (2nd) example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's recommended to return a function with `name` as argument from the computed property :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    names: [{
        firstName: 'Mike',
        lastName: 'McDonald',
        done: false
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Alex',
        lastName: 'Nemeth',
        done: false
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Nate',
        lastName: 'Kostansek',
        done: true
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Ivan',
        lastName: 'Wyrsta',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
     fullName(){
      return (name)=>name.lastName + ', ' + name.firstName;
    },
     toggle() {
       return (name)=>name.done = !name.done;
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <ol>
    <li v-for='name in names'>
      <input type='checkbox' v-bind:checked='name.done' v-on:change='toggle(name)' />
      <span v-if='!name.done'>{{ fullName(name) }}</span>
      <del v-else>{{ fullName(name) }}</del>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Another solution is to loop through `names` array inside a computed property by concatenating `firstname` and `lastname`, after that return this array and loop through it in your template

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    names: [{
        firstName: 'Mike',
        lastName: 'McDonald',
        done: false
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Alex',
        lastName: 'Nemeth',
        done: false
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Nate',
        lastName: 'Kostansek',
        done: true
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Ivan',
        lastName: 'Wyrsta',
        done: true
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    fullNames() {
      return this.names.map(name => {
        let fl = {};
        fl.fname = name.firstName + ", " + name.lastName;
        fl.done = name.done;
        return fl;
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fullName: function(name) {
      return name.lastName + ', ' + name.firstName;
    },
    toggle: function(name) {
      name.done = !name.done;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <ol>
    <li v-for='name in fullNames'>
      <input type='checkbox' v-bind:checked='name.done' v-on:change='toggle(name)' />
      <span v-if='!name.done'>{{ name.fname }}</span>
      <del v-else>{{  name.fname  }}</del>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems that if having to loop through each `name` in `names` in a Computed property, it would be easier to set up a method.

Comment: i added a second solution using computed property

Comment: methods does not cache the result so it will be re-run every time the component or page render

Comment: @TomasLucena thank you for your comment, I changed it to computed property that returns a function with name as parameter. At those early days I didn't know about this tip

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the 'computed' with a parameter.
Most probably you want to use a method:

example

```
<span>{{ fullName('Hi') }}</span>

methods: {
  fullName(param) {
      return `${this.param} ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
  }
}
```